# Why does my AD7541AKN chip heat up?

Tags: power-dissipation

I am trying to use the circuit mentioned in the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD7541A.pdf) page 4 figure 4. But instead of using the op amp mentioned, I am using a lm324 to avoid using +-15v rails. I have triple checked the connections, but as soon as I turn on my circuit the chip heats up. I tried it with two different chips but every time the chip heats up as soon as I turn on the circuit. What may be the problem?

**Edit** Would keeping the BIT values as floating cause this? Because right now they are not connected to anything.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of what you're doing? How hot does the chip get? Can you copy the circuit diagram from the datasheet into the question?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot right now.

Comment: Are you aware that with a positive voltage reference on the DAC and with the op-amp circuit you are using, you will need a negative supply rail? Which chip gets hot - the DAC or the LM324?

Comment: The DAC gets pretty hot

Comment: The LM324 is probably winning with drive strength. You need a bipolar supply on your opamp for this to work, and your output is _always_ negative. See figure 7, page 6 for what you need to do to use it as single supply. I'd suggest just getting a unipolar DAC. Quite possibly would even be cheaper.

Comment: Leaving the bit values floating is certainly not reccomended; at least ground all of them.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this happens due to floating bit values. Do not keep the bit values floating.